Ubuntu 24.04.1+ Eclipse + Wayland + AMD GPU killing session
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my computer and I'm experiencing a very annoying error involving Wayland and Eclipse.
When starting Eclipse on Wayland, depending on the action I take (for example, using a context menu or repositioning a tab), Linux simply ends my session and closes all programs.
I've tried everything, and the only workaround I've managed is to start Eclipse using X11, which sometimes also causes a screen problem, but in this case, it's easier to deal with because only Eclipse freezes, and I just need to restart it.
I've tried starting Ubuntu itself using X11, but the system experiences an absurd keyboard input lag. This problem was reported here:
Here's the English translation of the additional information you provided:
Ubuntu 24.04 with keyboard input lag
I also can't find any log errors because it's an entire session being closed, not just an Eclipse crash.
I'm using Eclipse 06/2024 and my computer has the following config:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic
Shell: zsh 5.9
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 46.0
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X (12) @ 4.000GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT/6750 XT / 6800M/6850M XT
Memory: 7970MiB / 31997MiB

PS: As of now, AMD has not released a specific driver for Noble
